# Rails4: How can I use truncate method for the data retrieved Model.all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I use `truncate` method for the data retrieved all from model?

I'd like to truncate the `content` data in the article model like `<%= truncate(content, length: 50) %>`.

\views\articles\index.html.erb

```
<ul class="users">
  ...
  <%= render @articles %>
  ...
</ul>
```

\controllers\article_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all(limit: 10)
  end
  ...
```

article table

```
sqlite> .schema articles
CREATE TABLE "articles" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "content" varchar(255),"user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "category_id" integer);
```

Comment: So is `<%= truncate(content, length: 50) %>` not working? That should truncate the 'content' data. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate

Comment: When you do <%= render @articles %> Rails will try to render each article using a `_article` partial. How does `views\articles\_article.html.erb` looks like?

Comment: It works! Thank you @ Nerian. I change my code like `<%= simple_format(truncate(article.content, length: 50)) %>` instead of `<%= simple_format(article.content) %>` in `views\articles\article.html.erb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, since you are using

```
<%= render @article %>
```

Rails will search for an _article partial in the views/articles directory so you have to create one if you haven't created one already and it would be something like that

views/articles/_article.html.erb

```
<%= truncate(article.content, :length => 50) %>
.
.
```

Comment: It works! Thank you @Aalaa Mohamed. I change my code like `<%= simple_format(truncate(article.content, length: 50)) %>` instead of `<%= simple_format(article.content) %>` in `views\articles\article.html.erb`.